# NativeSQLQueryPlan in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, out-of-memory

I want to know that why hibernate generates `NativeSQLQueryPlan` (query plan for native queries). Also, how can I skip query cache plan for my native queries?

I am doing some bulk data operation, and there I am firing native queries, but I am getting `OutOfMemoryException` because hibernate is caching `ResultSet` and query plans. I only have native queries in my logic (no named query).